# python rename field json with specific structure

Tags: python, json, rename

i have a json with structure:

```
{
" features": [
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon", 
    "coordinates": []
  }, 
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
    "ADMIN_LEVE": "REGION", 
    "POPULTION": 4363916, 
    "GEO_CENTER": "7.923209152686669, 45.06052300898206", 
    "ID": "01", 
    "NAME": "PIEMONTE"
  }
}

]
}
```

and i need to rename the field "ADMIN_LEVE".
I have write a code using pandas to rename but doesn't work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.rename(columns={'ADMIN_LEVE':'ADMIN_LEVEL'}, inplace=True)
```

I can i do it?

i have also tryied with replace but doesn't work

```
json_data=open(path + ".json").read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
for d in data:
      d.replace('"ADMIN_LEVE"', '"ADMIN_LEVEL"')
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you "have" to use pandas?

Comment: I have seen a example with pandas but if there is other way it's not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source JSON (as string):

```
In [325]: print(s)

{
" features": [
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": []
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "ADMIN_LEVE": "REGION",
    "POPULTION": 4363916,
    "GEO_CENTER": "7.923209152686669, 45.06052300898206",
    "ID": "01",
    "NAME": "PIEMONTE"
  }
}

]
}
```

Replaced:

```
In [327]: s = s.replace('"ADMIN_LEVE":', '"ADMIN_LEVEL":')

In [328]: print(s)

{
" features": [
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": []
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "ADMIN_LEVEL": "REGION",
    "POPULTION": 4363916,
    "GEO_CENTER": "7.923209152686669, 45.06052300898206",
    "ID": "01",
    "NAME": "PIEMONTE"
  }
}

]
}
```

**UPDATE:** helper function:

```
def replace_in_json_file(filename, from_str, to_str):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read()
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data.replace(from_str, to_str))
```

Comment: No pandas needed.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston, yeah, sometimes we don't need Pandas (shocked :-D) Thank you!

Comment: Converting json to string is clever, didn't think of that

Comment: @SuperStew, thank you! Actually JSON is a long string ;-)

Comment: I have my json file into folder so i can read it as string and after replace, but after run script if i open json file, the replace not work

Comment: @APPGIS, did you overwrite your JSON file with the replaced JSON string?

Comment: Yes, but my json file have more same element to replace, using your help I receive the error:json.dump(data.replace(from_str, to_str), f)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'